# How to use CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes with a byte[] coming from a jpg image

Tags: c#, image, uwp, win2d

I have a JPG image available as a byte[] in memory.

I need to create a CanvasBitmap to draw this image that ultimately creates a CompositionDrawingSurface that I can assign to my SpriteVisual. And I need a super-fast method to do this!!

I accomplished the task successfully using `CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(ICanvasResourceCreator, IRandomAccessStream)`, but this approach takes too much (more than 10 milliseconds), while using `CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(ICanvasResourceCreator, byte[], int, int, DirectXPixelFormat)` it just takes 1 millisecond, which is ok with my performance requirements.

Unfortunately, using `CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes` the result is not the correct image, but rather a cloud of dots, which makes me thinking there is a problem in the encoding / decoding of the image.

Here's the code I tried:

```
byte[] imgBytes = await ReadBinaryFile(path); // read the binary content of a JPG image, for the example purpose (in the real environment, the byte[] comes from in memory caches...)

using (CanvasBitmap canvasBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(s_canvasDevice, imgBytes, 600, 800, DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized))
{
    // Draw the image to the surface
    using (CanvasDrawingSession session = CanvasComposition.CreateDrawingSession(surface))
    {
        session.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
        session.DrawImage(canvasBitmap, new Rect(0, 0, 600, 800), new Rect(0, 0, 600, 800));
    }
}
```

What am I missing?
How can I treat the `byte[] imgBytes` so that it can be useful as input of `CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes`?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't you need to convert from JPEG (compressed) format to raw byte array first?

Comment: Thanks @nbura, do you have a fast method to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know a fast method, sorry about that. But why not save the images in a different format other than JPEG, if you want to avoid the time spent decompressing?

Comment: @nbura that made the trick! Would you like to put as answer so that I mark as accepted?

Comment: Sure! Glad to hear it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert from JPEG (compressed) format to raw byte array first. You can't directly read a JPEG image off disk with `ReadBinaryFile()` and display it.

I'm guessing that much of the performance issue is coming from the time it takes for `LoadAsync()` to decompress the JPEG. You could probably improve performance by saving in a different, uncompressed image format.

---

Also, if you really do need to read JPEGs, or if it's still slow even with other image formats: There might be some way to make use of `LoadAsync()` to load multiple files in parallel. But I don't know how to do this, and it might not be that helpful if you're being bottlenecked by the file I/O anyways. Just a thought.